# Grouping by id and 2nd column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a stored proc that returns three columns

```
| ID | EVENTS_ID | EVENT_TIME_FROM | 
| 46 | 1 | "2015-03-09 15:00:00" |
| 46 | 2 | "2015-03-16 15:00:00" |
| 46 | 3 | "2015-03-18 15:00:00" |
| 47 | 4 | "2015-03-12 16:30:00" |
| 47 | 5 | "2015-03-23 16:30:00" |
| 47 | 6 | "2015-03-23 16:30:00" |
| 47 | 7 | "2015-03-23 16:30:00" |
| 47 | 8 | "2015-03-23 16:30:00" |
```

I want to query for all the id + events_ids given the max EVENT_TIME_FROM per ID

i.e. result would be

```
| ID | EVENTS_ID | EVENT_TIME_FROM | 
| 46 | 3 | "2015-03-18 15:00:00" |
| 47 | 5 | "2015-03-23 16:30:00" |
| 47 | 6 | "2015-03-23 16:30:00" |
| 47 | 7 | "2015-03-23 16:30:00" |
| 47 | 8 | "2015-03-23 16:30:00" |
```

Also to make this more difficult the table is actually the result of a stored proc call and some group by already.

i.e. current query is

```
SELECT DISTINCT id,events_id, event_time_from
FROM my_stored_proc(...data)
GROPU BY id, events_id, event_time_from
ORDER BY id ,events_id ,event_time_from DESC
```

I am on Postgres, tried a few things but unsure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a ranking function such as `rank()`:

```
select id,events_id, event_time_from,
from (
    select id,events_id, event_time_from,
        rank() over (partition by id order by event_time_from desc) rnk
    from my_stored_proc(...data)
) t 
where rnk = 1
```

---

Alternatively, you could join the results back to themselves using the `max()` aggregate:

```
select m.id,m.events_id,m.event_time_from
from my_stored_proc(...data) m
    join (
        select id, max(event_time_from) event_time_from
        from my_stored_proc(...data)
        group by id
   ) t on m.id = t.id and m.event_time_from = t.event_time_from
```